# Toggle output lines on a PIC24FJ64GB110 processor

Tags: pic

I am new to PIC processors, but not new in embedded systems, M16, 8051 etc...

I am trying to do some very basic tasks: like toggle a I/O line.

I have a 5K pull-up resistor on Pin 34 (100 pin chip, PortB10). The problem is, pin34 is always high, never goes down.

```
void main()

{

  _TRISB10 = 0;  // RB10 output

  _ODB10 = 1;    // open-drain 

  Nop();

  Nop();

  _LATB10 = 0;  // or _LATB10 = 1


  while(1)
  {}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether that pin is a A/D or comparator input.  On reset, all pins that can be analog inputs are configured that way.  To use them for digital I/O requires configuring them to digital.  Different PICs do that different ways.  Take a look at the applicable A/D and comparator chapters of the family reference manual to see how to make analog-capable pins digital.  To find the right family reference chapters, look in the datasheet for your particular part.  Each peripheral will have a brief overview in the datasheet, and the family reference manual chapter that applies to that peripheral will be listed at the beginning of the datasheet chapter.

Until you get things working, try using the pin in regular push-pull output mode.  You can use open drain later once you get it working.  For now, that just adds another possibility for screwup.

Comment: That pin is shared with AN10, but a pin shared with an analogue input that is left in the default analogue input state can be used for digital output. It's only digital input that is affected.

Comment: Thanks Olin, Leon:

I am still in the learning curve on PIC. I copy/paste some code from internet:

//_CONFIG1(JTAGEN_OFF  & GWRP_OFF & BKBUG_ON & COE_OFF & ICS_PGx2 & FWDTEN_OFF & FNOSC_PRI)
//_CONFIG2(FNOSC_PRI & FCKSM_CSDCMD & OSCIOFNC_OFF & POSCMOD_HS)

The above two lines do not work.


These two lines are working fine:

_CONFIG1(FWDTEN_OFF & ICS_PGx2)
_CONFIG2(IESO_ON & FNOSC_PRI & FCKSM_CSECME & POSCMOD_HS & PLLDIV_DIV2 & IOL1WAY_OFF)

I will spend more time to understand this.

Cheers

Wei